# Magento 2 add custom external url to product

Tags: magento2, product, url-key

I'm doing an e-commerce site that instead of having products it will have overview of properties, but this properties are stored in an external website.

I need to add an external url to the products, for example Propertie 1 has this link:

https://example.com/property1

I tried to change the url in Search Engine Optimization  and Url Key but it does not allow me to add a custom url.

Greetings!

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the Url Rewrites using following steps :

1. On the Admin Panel, Marketing > SEO & Search > URL Rewrites.
2. In the upper-right corner, click on the Add URL Rewrites button.
3. From the dropdown list of Create URL Rewrites, choose “For Product” option.
4. In the product list that appears instantly, click on the product which needs to be redirected to edit.
5. Hit the Skip Category Selection button, then navigate to the URL Rewrite Information section.

Update the Index:

1. On the Admin Panel, System > Tools > Index Management.
2. Mark the Catalog URL Rewrites checkbox.
3. Choose Reindex Data for the Action.
4. Submit to update the index.

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, I have tried this, but it did not work, in Request Path it does not allow me to type urls like  http://example.com